# I am trying to run my app in background . But service Class is not working in background

Tags: android, android-studio, service, background-process, countdown

It is an app that calculates some data and I want it to work in background if the app is closed. Here is my code

Here is the main activity.

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    RadioButton selectedRdb;
    RadioGroup gender;
    EditText drinkingTime;
    EditText bodyweight;
    EditText volume;

    EditText size;
    Intent counterIntent;

    String genderOfThePerson;
    Button start;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        gender = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.genderRbGroup);

        drinkingTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.juontiAika);
        bodyweight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.kehonPaino);

        volume = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.vahvuus);
        size = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.koko);
        start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startBtn);
        counterIntent = new Intent(this, Counter.class);
    }


    public void startCounter(View view) {
        if(gender.getCheckedRadioButtonId()==-1)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select Gender", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            int selectedId = gender.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            selectedRdb = (RadioButton)findViewById(selectedId);
            if(selectedRdb.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("male")){
                genderOfThePerson = "male";
            }
            else if(selectedRdb.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("female")){
                genderOfThePerson = "female";
            }

        }


        int bodyWeight = Integer.parseInt(bodyweight.getText().toString());

        double drinkSize = Double.parseDouble(size.getText().toString());
        drinkSize = drinkSize/10;

        double drinkVolume = Double.parseDouble(volume.getText().toString());
        double drinkingtime = Double.parseDouble(drinkingTime.getText().toString());

        //muutetaan juomisaika tunneiksi
        drinkingtime = drinkingtime / 60;

        counterIntent.putExtra("juomankoko", drinkSize);
        counterIntent.putExtra("juomanvahvuus", drinkVolume);
        counterIntent.putExtra("sukupuoli", genderOfThePerson);
        counterIntent.putExtra("kehonpaino", bodyWeight);

        counterIntent.putExtra("juontiaika", drinkingtime);

        startActivity(counterIntent);




    }




}
```

Here is Counter Activity :-

```
    package com.mypackage.henri.beerdrinkreminder;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.mypackage.henri.beerdrinkreminder.Un.MainActivity;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Counter extends AppCompatActivity {

    Intent mainactivityIntent;
    Intent serviceIntent;
    TextView promilletTxt;
    TextView kanniAika;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_counter);

        mainactivityIntent  = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        promilletTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bacTxt);
        kanniAika = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.känniAika);

        Button drinkButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.drinkBtn);
        Button lopetaBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopBtn);
        Intent i = getIntent();



        //GETS THE USER INFO VARIABLES FROM INTENT AND SENDS THE FORWARD TO THE SERVICE
        serviceIntent = new Intent(Counter.this, CounterService.class);

        serviceIntent.putExtra("juomankoko", i.getDoubleExtra("juomankoko", 0));
        serviceIntent.putExtra("juomanvahvuus", i.getDoubleExtra("juomanvahvuus", 0));
        serviceIntent.putExtra("sukupuoli", i.getStringExtra("sukupuoli"));
        serviceIntent.putExtra("kehonpaino", i.getIntExtra("kehonpaino", 0));
        serviceIntent.putExtra("juontiaika", i.getDoubleExtra("juontiaika",0));

        startService(serviceIntent);
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(CounterService.BROADCAST_ACTION));






        drinkButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //THIS IS FOR ADDING ANOTHER DRINK WHEN THE CALCULATOR IS ALREADY RUNNING
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Counter.this);
                View dView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.drinkdialog,null);
                final EditText dSize = (EditText)dView.findViewById(R.id.drinkSize);
                final EditText dTime = (EditText)dView.findViewById(R.id.drinkingTime);
                final EditText dStrenght = (EditText)dView.findViewById(R.id.juomanVahvuus);
                Button submitBtn = (Button)dView.findViewById(R.id.drinkBtn);

                builder.setView(dView);
                final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

                dialog.show();

                submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if(dSize.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                            Toast.makeText(Counter.this, "Add the size of the drink", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else if(dTime.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                            Toast.makeText(Counter.this, "Add the drinking time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else{
                            double juomankoko = Double.parseDouble(dSize.getText().toString());
                            double juontiaika = Double.parseDouble(dTime.getText().toString());
                            double juomanvahvuus = Double.parseDouble(dStrenght.getText().toString());

                            serviceIntent.putExtra("juomankoko", juomankoko);
                            serviceIntent.putExtra("juontiaika", juontiaika);
                            serviceIntent.putExtra("juomanvahvuus", juomanvahvuus);

                            //THIS IS ID IS FOR CHECKING WHERE DID THE START REQUEST COME FROM. IF THE ID IS NOT 0,
                            // THEN THE SERVICE HAS ALREADY STARTED ATLEAST ONCE AND THE ALCOHOL CALCULATOR HAS BEEN CREATED ALREADY.
                            serviceIntent.putExtra("id", 123);

                            //STARTS SERVICE AGAIN
                            startService(serviceIntent);
                            dialog.cancel();

                        }
                    }
                });



            }
        });

        //THIS BUTTON IS FOR CANCELLING THE CALCULATIONS
        lopetaBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Counter.this);
                View dView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.lopetusdialogi,null);

                TextView bac = (TextView) dView.findViewById(R.id.bac);
                TextView aikaaPäisn = (TextView)dView.findViewById(R.id.aikaaPäisn);
                /*bac.setText(alcCal.calculateCurrentBac(palamisVauhtiSekunissa) + "%");

                double aika = (alcCal.getGrammat() / palamisVauhtiSekunissa) / 3600;
                int tunnit = (int)Math.floor(aika);
                int minuutit = (int)Math.floor((aika - tunnit) * 60);

                aikaaPäisn.setText(tunnit + " hours " + minuutit + " minutes");
                */
                builder.setView(dView);
                final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

                dialog.show();

                Button dialoginLopetus = (Button)dView.findViewById(R.id.dialoginLopetus);

                dialoginLopetus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        startActivity(mainactivityIntent);
                    }
                });


            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        startService(serviceIntent);
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(CounterService.BROADCAST_ACTION));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
        startService(new Intent(this, CounterService.class));
     //   registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(CounterService.BROADCAST_ACTION));

    }

    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            updateUI(intent);
        }
    };

    private void updateUI(Intent intent) {

        //THIS METHOD GETS THE CALCULATED ALCOHOL LEVEL AND TIME FROM THE PARAMETER INTENT AND DISPLAYS IT IN THE TEXTVIEWS
        double promillet = intent.getDoubleExtra("promillet", 0.0);
        double aikaPäisn = intent.getDoubleExtra("aika", 0.0);
        double grammat = intent.getDoubleExtra("grammat", 0.0);

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.000");



        int tunnit = (int)Math.floor(aikaPäisn);
        int minuutit = (int)Math.floor((aikaPäisn - tunnit) * 60);

        promilletTxt.setText(df.format(promillet) + " %");
        kanniAika.setText(tunnit + " hours " + minuutit + " minutes");

    }
}
```

I am trying to run this app when I destroy all activity.
Here is my Counter Service

```
package com.mypackage.henri.beerdrinkreminder;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class CounterService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "CounterService";
    private Intent intent;
    public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.mypackage.henri.beerdrinkreminder.CounterService";

    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    AlcoholCalc alcCalc;

    //VARIABLES FOR THE CALCULATIONS
    double palamisVauhtiSekunissa;
    double promillet;
    private int aloitusLukema = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      //  intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        aloitusLukema++;

        //THIS IS FOR CHECKING IF THE SERVICE IS STARTED FOR THE FIRST TIME. IF IT IS, THEN WE CONSTRUCT THE ALCOHOL CALCULATOR.



        if(aloitusLukema == 1){



            int kehonpaino = intent.getIntExtra("kehonpaino", 0);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+kehonpaino,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            double juomanKoko = intent.getDoubleExtra("juomankoko", 0.0);

            double juomanVahvuus = intent.getDoubleExtra("juomanvahvuus", 0.0);

            double juontiaika = (intent.getDoubleExtra("juontiaika", 0.0));

            String sukupuoli = intent.getStringExtra("sukupuoli");


            alcCalc = new AlcoholCalc(sukupuoli,
                    kehonpaino,
                    juomanVahvuus,
                    juontiaika,
                    juomanKoko);
            double palamisvauhtiTunnissa = kehonpaino / 10;

            palamisVauhtiSekunissa = palamisvauhtiTunnissa / 3600;



        }
       /*
        //THIS SECTION IS DONE IF THE USER PRESSES THE DRINK-BUTTON IN COUNTER ACVITIVY AND ADDS ANOTHER DRINK.
        else if (intent.getIntExtra("id", 0) != 0){

            double juomanKoko = intent.getDoubleExtra("juomankoko", 0.0);

            double juomanVahvuus = intent.getDoubleExtra("juomanvahvuus", 0.0);

            double juontiaika = (intent.getDoubleExtra("juontiaika", 0.0));

            alcCalc.drinkABeer(juomanKoko/10, juontiaika, juomanVahvuus);

        }
        */

        handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
        handler.postDelayed(sendUpdatesToUI, 1000);

        return START_STICKY;

    }

    private Runnable sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            AlcCalculations();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };

    private void AlcCalculations() {

        //THIS IS FOR CALCULATING THE ALCOHOL LEVEL
        promillet = alcCalc.calculateCurrentBac(palamisVauhtiSekunissa);


        double aikaTunteina = (alcCalc.getGrammat() / palamisVauhtiSekunissa) / 3600;

        intent.putExtra("aika", aikaTunteina);
        intent.putExtra("promillet", promillet);
        intent.putExtra("grammat", alcCalc.getGrammat());
        sendBroadcast(intent);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);

    }



    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


}
```

The app runs well in OnPause State. When I close the app it shows some error message :-

```
11-14 04:59:15.149 3539-3539/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.mypackage.henri.beerdrinkreminder.CounterService@536765c8 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2507)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:130)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                     at com.mypackage.henri.beerdrinkreminder.CounterService.onStartCommand(CounterService.java:46)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2490)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
11-14 04:59:17.345 3539-3539/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3539 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

remove Toast from your service

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+kehonpaino,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

***An Service has a few limitations:
It can't interact directly with your user interface.***

Answer (score 0):

By default a service runs on the main thread only. You will have to either handle new thread creation and handling in onStartCommand function of the service or use a IntentService which be default starts a new background thread.

Comment: Would you please add some more details about the problem so that I can clarify it.

Comment: Whenever you start a service in android, it starts in the same process and on the main thread only (if it is running already). To make it run on a new thread, in service's onStartCommand function, create a new thread and do your work on that thread. Or there is an option available in android called IntentService which is basically an extension of service class only but handles this new thread creation by itself. You can extend IntentService and implement its onHandleIntent method. It will run on a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

In your onStartCommand() method, you are returning the flag **START_STICKY**. This flag is used when your OS kills the service and it could be

1. **START_STICKY**: If the Service process is terminated by the system, the Service is going to be restarted and no processed Intents will be delivered to the onStartCommand function. When no start Intents are pending for delivery, a null Intent is passed to the onStartCommand function. If a start request didn't return before the system kills the Service, the start request is submitted again on the restarted Service passing START_FLAG_RETRY on the onStartCommand second argument.
2. **START_NOT_STICKY**: If the Service is terminated by the system, the Service is only restarted when there is at least one pending start request to be delivered.
3. **START_REDELIVER_INTENT**: If the Service is terminated by the system, the Service will be restarted redelivering the last delivered start Intent and any pending requests. This kind of service is similar to START_STICKY, but instead of delivering a null Intent in the start command, the last successfully delivered Intent is dispatched. When the start request is redelivered, the flag START_ FLAG_REDELIVERY is passed in on the onStartCommand second argument.

When you are closing the app, you are killing the process in which the service resides.

I would suggest you return **START_NOT_STICKY** or **START_REDELIVER_INTENT** and check if it is working or not.
Also, check if the issue gets resolved after adding the attribute **android:stopTask = "false"**, in the service tag of the manifest file, which basically doesn't kill the service when the app gets killed.

Go through this link if you still have some doubts:
[Understanding Android Services](http://codetheory.in/understanding-android-started-bound-services/)